# How to remove Click location after TranslateAnimation?

Tags: android, animation

I have full screen RelativeLayout that contains the following:
1. FrameLayout, full screen, displaying content.
2. LinearLayout, act as a control menu, stay on top of the content #1, must be able to slide or fade in/out on request(I actually have two of these. One at the top of the screen, another at the bottom).

I have the view display correctly, the menu controller slide/fade in and out when menu button pressed. But when I slide and fade the view out, the click action remain. How do I remove this action?

I tried to call menuLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE); but the action remains.

I read some issue with TranslateAnimation but I cannot get it to work.
Can someone tell me how do I fix this? Example would be appreciated.

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<FrameLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="#99000000"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:id="@+id/contentFrame"
    >
    <ViewSwitcher 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/viewSwitch">
        <include layout="@layout/main_car" />
    </ViewSwitcher>
</FrameLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="43dp"
    android:background="@drawable/um_top_bar"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/topMenu"
    android:gravity="top"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/um_btn_home"
        android:id="@+id/homeMainBtn"  />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/exp_menu_btn"
        android:id="@+id/menuMainBtn"  />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FF000000"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/bottomMenu"
    android:gravity="top"
    >
    <include layout="@layout/menu_bottom" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got it to work at last. For anyone who may face the same problem, here's what I did.

I place empty layer and separate all menu content into separate XML file.

Here's the code:

```
    /** Resetting bottom menu content */
    private void resetBottomMenu(boolean isOpen){

    bottomMenu.removeAllViews();
    bottomMenu.addView(loadBottomMenu(isOpen));
            // Control event handler goes here.
    }

    /** Load bottom menu content from XML */
    private LinearLayout loadBottomMenu(boolean isOpen){

    LinearLayout result = null;
    if(isOpen){
        result = (LinearLayout)View.inflate(this.getApplicationContext(), R.layout.menu_bottom_open, null);
    }else{
        result = (LinearLayout)View.inflate(this.getApplicationContext(), R.layout.menu_bottom, null);
    }
    return result;
    }
```

Every time I want to slide menu in, I called resetBottomMenu then start animation on bottomMenu. If I want to close the menu, I start animation then resetBottomMenu.

It's important to remove child view in that Layout since that will remove the click action.

P.S. I'm not sure if this is the best way of doing it but I can confirm that it works. I have three menu that need to be fade/slide and they work perfectly now :)